# how to paste a delimited string into multiple fields (eg credit card)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms, credit-card

I have a form in angular with 3 standard inputs fields (text) in a row which together form a redemption code (like a credit card number).

We are having trouble working out how allow the user to paste a full code into the first field and have it populate all 3. eg code 'xx xxxx xxxx'

Comment: Ur code looks like....

Comment: try input mask jquery.See demo [page](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: why not use one field like everyone else in the world does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jquery input mask` for currency,date,card number,Telephone number etc.

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.card_number').mask('000 0000 0000');    
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="card_number">
```

Comment: I think what OP what is that he want to split the input and populate the 3 fields like credit card input forms not adding delimiters.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam - if user starts typing then.

Comment: OP didn't mention, but that once the limit of the first textbox reached the focus should automatically goes to the next one and so on.

Comment: currently the client is sending out the codes space delimited (xx xxxx xxxx) so pattern matching would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can do the following

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="tb0" />
     <input type="text" id="tb1" />
     <input type="text" id="tb2" />
    <input type="text" id="tb3" />
</form>

$('#tb0').on('paste',function(){
 var element = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var splittedString = $('#tb0').val().match(/.{1,4}/g)
    for(var i=0; i<splittedString.length; i++){
        $('#tb' + i).val(splittedString[i]);
    }
  }, 0);
})
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinaidoron/n88e132L/)

Comment: note that paste event isn't available 100% cross browser

Comment: but what if user starts typing instead of pasting.

Comment: @Bugfixer with paste you don't have a problem, if you implement it using keyup event you might need to overcome this

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a go.
re paste - it's more for if paste is available and yes, continuous typing is also desired, but was thinking of a watcher that re-focused while typing.

Comment: Does paste event not work on IE or any of the popular browsers ?